# tensorflow - Unexpected behavior of per_process_gpu_memory_fraction

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, memory, nvidia

I am trying to limit the gpu memory usage to exactly 10% of the gpu memory, but according to nvidia-smi the below program uses about 13% of the gpu. Is this expected behavior? If it is expected behavior, what is the other approximately 3-4% coming from?

```
from time import sleep

i = tf.constant(0)
x = tf.constant(10)
r = tf.add(i,x)

# Use at most 10% of gpu memory, I expect this to set a hard limit
gpu_options = tf.GPUOptions(per_process_gpu_memory_fraction=.1)

# sleep is used to see what nvidia-smi says for gpu memory usage, 
# I expect that it will be at most 10% of gpu memory (which is 1616.0 mib for my gpu)
# but instead I see the process using up to 2120 mib 
with tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(gpu_options=gpu_options)) as sess:
        sess.run(r);
        sleep(10)
```

See this github issue for more details about my environment and gpu: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/22158

Answer (score 0):

From my experimentation, it looks like cudnn and cublas context initialization take around 228 mb of memory. Also, the cuda context can take from 50 to 118 mb.